# Messages sending(?) but not getting proper response back?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

Setup project, added test user, gave it access to Firebase permissions.  Using the Google developer playground I have an OAUTH2 key but when I post a message to my project like

https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/xxx/messages:send

with the JSON body of:

```
{
    "message": {
        "token": "xxx",
        "data": {
            "body": "Test",
            "title": "Test",
            "key_1": "Test",
            "key_2": "Test"
        }
    }
}
```

Using the FCM key from my browser

The message never arrives and Firebase simply responds with the name of the project.  Complete headers here.

```
POST /v1/projects/xxx/messages:send HTTP/1.1
Host: fcm.googleapis.com
Content-length: 433
Content-type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ya29.xxx

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-length: 89
X-xss-protection: 0
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
Server: scaffolding on HTTPServer2
-content-encoding: gzip
Cache-control: private
Date: Wed, 20 Mar 2024 12:22:38 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
  "name": "projects/xxx/messages/93c5c387-86ea-4cfc-8f19-de3de344ef59"
}
```

But again, no message arrives at any browser and the Messaging panel does not show any messages being sent.

Thoughts?